# Relocating central air conditioner coolant supply line

Tags: air-conditioning, central-air

I have a central air conditioner installed in the attic with the supply line running down the back of the house and into the condenser. What I wanted to know if I can move the condenser onto the side of the house and have the  supply line ran from the basement and into the unit.

[image: run supply line]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Technically, you can have the condenser unit anywhere you want. You just need a pathway for the freon supply line and the electric lines. Ideally, the closer the air handler and condenser unit are, the better the cooling will be so that needs to be a factor. If you're moving everything around, you might want to consider getting the air handler out of the attic.

Comment: How big of a pathway do I need ? Can I run it up against the sewer pipe on the second floor?

Comment: @Jefferson  Just the width of the tubing and insulation that's on the existing unit. Pathway might be the wrong term. You just need to get from one unit to the other.

Comment: Well, *you* can’t, but a licensed A/C guy with the necessary vampire equipment can do that.  It’s absolutely vital that old freon be sucked out of the system and taken to qualified recyclers (it’s polished into “new” freon).  That is because leaking it to atmosphere damages the ozone layer (for real) and some refrigerants are no longer made - what’s recycled is **it**.